# Loopback 4 keep alive when datasource error

Tags: javascript, sql-server, loopback

I use the Loopback 4 framework in my app service. In my app service, I have a main datasource and 2 more external datasources (SQL server). Sometimes the external datasources are unavailable and the app service crashes when an endpoint is called there. I cannot control when datasource is available or not.

Is there a way to prevent the appservice crashing when this happens?

Thanks

All datasources have the property "lazyConnect", but this property doesn't work in this situation.